# Has anyone tried to monitor kbfs with incrond?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, unison, keybase, incron, incrond

While I am able to run `unison -batch keybase` and everything works fine, I tried this in [incron](https://github.com/ar-/incron)tab:

```
/run/user/1000/keybase/kbfs/ IN_ALL_EVENTS flock -n /tmp/synclock unison -batch keybase
```

with the syslog result:

```
Nov 24 03:53:05 ThinkPad incrond[5820]: access denied on /run/user/1000/keybase/kbfs/ - events will be discarded silently
Nov 24 03:53:05 ThinkPad incrond[5820]: cannot create watch for user me: (13) Permission denied
```

incrond is running as root and "unconfined", which I presume relates to selinux (?)

```
$ ps -eo euser,ruser,suser,fuser,f,comm,label | grep incron
root     root     root     root     5 incrond         unconfined
```

Any thoughts on what might be going on?

Comment: A number of people are trying to solve this or a parallel problem, for example [here](https://github.com/keybase/kbfs/issues/1592).  So I don't think the downvote is appropriate.  My own answer shows that there is no easy answer forthcoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that /run/user/1000/keybase/kbfs/ is a FUSE filesystem that is mounted without the option "allow_root", so it is only accessible via the user that mounted the FS.  Adding "allow_root" to /etc/fuse.conf does not solve the issue as the kbfs code does not pass through this option.  To do that, you have to edit the code and recompile.

It also turns out that even if kbfs allowed root access - and incron or inotify do need root access - FUSE in addition does not have a way of reporting filesystem events.  Though it would apparently be [possible](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/wiki/Fsnotify-and-FUSE), the developers have [labeled it a "won't fix"](https://github.com/rfjakob/gocryptfs/issues/215).  That means [running keybase as root](https://github.com/keybase/client/issues/11594) will also not solve the problem.

My solution is to just run a cron job that syncs the directories every 60 seconds.  There is a file in /keybase that is always present, even if it doesn't show up under `ls`: /keybase/kbfs.error.txt.  The contents of that can be used to identify whether kbfs is mounted.  If so, a batch job can be run to sync the directories using unison.